# Ext JS multiple series chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, store

I want to create a line chart with 3 different series using ExtJS 4.2.1, but only one of them is displayed, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I take data from XML file and add it to the store:

```
Ext.each(arrayOfHeaps, function(item) {
                            var storeObject;
                            if (item.description === 'HeapTotal') {
                                storeObject = {'heapTotalValue': item.value, 'heapTotalDate': new Date(item.date)};
                            }
                            else if (item.description === 'HeapUsed') {
                                storeObject = {'heapUsedValue': item.value, 'heapUsedDate': new Date(item.date)};
                            }
                            else {
                                storeObject = {'heapFreeValue': item.value, 'heapFreeDate': new Date(item.date)};
                            }
                            store.add(storeObject);
                        });
```

It seems to work fine. One element from store printed in console:

```
heapFreeDate:""
heapFreeValue:""
heapTotalDate:Thu May 11 2017 04:10:00 GMT+0200 (Środkowoeuropejski czas letni)
heapTotalValue:1607680
heapUsedDate:""
heapUsedValue:""
```

Code to create chart:

```
                    title: 'Wartość',
                    type: 'Numeric',
                    position: 'left',
                    fields: ['heapTotalValue', 'heapFreeValue', 'heapUsedValue'],
                    grid: true
                },{
                    title: 'Czas',
                    type: 'Time',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fields: ['heapTotalDate', 'heapFreeDate', 'heapUsedDate'],
                    dateFormat: 'H:i:s.u',
                    fromDate: new Date('2017-05-11T04:10:00.055+02:00'),
                    toDate: new Date('2017-05-11T12:30:00.005+02:00'),
                    grid: true
                }],
                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'tilingChart',
                    fields:['heapTotalValue', 'heapTotalDate'],
                    yField: 'heapTotalValue',
                    xField: 'heapTotalDate'
                },{
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'memoryChart',
                    fields:['heapFreeValue', 'heapFreeDate'],
                    xField: 'heapFreeValue',
                    yField: 'heapFreeDate'
                },{
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'defaultChart',
                    fields:['heapUsedValue', 'heapUsedDate'],
                    xField: 'heapUsedValue',
                    yField: 'heapUsedDate'
                }]
```

The chart is created, but second and third series are ignored

Comment: any demo link for your issue ?

Comment: Please check that you have added the axes properly to the chart. For X & Y you might need to add desired axis from the series.

Comment: @AnandSingh I  was looking for the solution everywhere else but I didn't check if x and y axis were defined in the right way (once x was a date, once it was a number). Such a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome! I too had same kind of difficulties while working on charts for the first time.